# cython class with an attributes as python object instance

Tags: cython

Let's have an example.

```py
cdef class Example:
    attr2 = None
    cdef attr3
    cdef object attr4
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = Obj()
        self.attr2 = Obj()
        self.attr3 = Obj()
        self.attr4 = Obj()
```

The line with the assignment to *self.attr1* will raise an *AttributeError* saying: "*object has no attribute 'attr1'*.

If try with the *self.attr2* it raises also the exception but with the message: "*object attribute 'attr2' is read-only*".

And if uses the keyword *cdef*, an it doesn't have an explicit type, the compilation process will fail.

If this attribute is defined with the type *object*, it looks nice. But different instances of the *Example* class will have this *attr4* like a singleton and any interaction with one of them will be visible for the other instances and, in this case, I want to have an Obj() instance unique for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
class Obj(object):
    # At first I define a class Obj() to match your example
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 32
        self.xyz = "xyzxyz"

# Then I can define the Example class
cdef class Example:
    cdef public:
        object attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = Obj()
        self.attr2 = Obj()
        self.attr3 = Obj()
        self.attr4 = Obj()
```

It seems to be cythonized/compiled without error and you have access to the attributes related to the `Obj` object :

```
In [11]:
a = Example()
a.attr1.abc
​
Out[11]:
32
```

Comment: The issue is when your have 2 Example() object, lets say 'a' and 'b'. If you modify a.attr1, you'll see this change in b.attr1 and all the other attributes.
Unless the issue I'm seeing is from the Obj class itself. I'm not sure. I'm using the logging module and this Obj() is a logger. I'll check if the issue comes from there...